# Seeking guidance on .htaccess to rewrite URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo

I am looking to make all the individual page being able to search in google search engine, so I am planning to modify the URL.

I want:

```
demo.com/profile/GTnum/2706
```

being read as:

```
demo.com/profile/?GTnum=2706
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^GTnum/(\d+)$    ?GTnum=$1 [L]
```

May anyone advice which part go wrong and can give some guidance on it? Thanks!!!!!

UPDATES
http://gttutor.com/tutor-profile/GTnum/2705

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+)/GTnum/(.*)$ /tutor-profile/?GTnum=$2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why should `demo.com/profile/?GTnum=2706` be more searchable than `demo.com/profile/GTnum/2706` ?

Comment: @B001ᛦ HI Sorry for my presentation, currently my website is a dynamic page, e.g. /tutor-profile/?GTnum=xxxx. So i wanna make it to a static page to make it more searchable, e.g. Tutor-profile/GTnum/xxx, but due to the PHP code behind. I want the url display as the static one, but on the back-end, i can still read the page like a dynamic to get the php variable GTnum. Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm not a big fan of .htaccess and don't now very much, but seems like this rule will help you:
 RewriteRule ^(.+)/GTnum/(.*)$ /profile/?GTnum=$2 [QSA]

So now if you put http://demo.com/profile/GTnum/2706
it will forward to
http://demo.com/profile/?GTnum=2706

I've tested here:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: @EugeneKapustin thanks for your advice. I believe this could be the correct answer. Yet, my site keep showing 404 error. What could be some of the possible reasons behind? i have attached my .htaccess for ur reference. Thanks!

Comment: @GTTutor why do you place this rule there? RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
take it out

Comment: is `tutor-profile` an actual file or is that path handled by `index.php`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the requested details so that this can be reopened and answered.